# Time analysis on BST

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

I know, time analysis of BST is O(h), where h is height of the tree.

Is it possible for a search on a BST take O(n) to complete?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. This tree for example:

```
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
       \
        5
         \
          6
           \
            7
             \
              8
```

It takes n (8) comparisons when looking for the value 8 or greater.